# How can I access all users blocked by request.user and all users who block request.user? Each is a foreign key in a Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model:

```
# Block: A user blocked by another user
class Block(models.Model):
    user_is_blocking = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_is_blocking")
    user_is_blocked = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_is_blocked")
```

How do I query all users blocked by a specific user? I was hoping to do something like this...

```
blocked_users = User.objects.get(id=request.user).user_is_blocking_set
```

but it generates this error message...

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'user_is_blocking_set'
```

I also need to query all other users that have blocked a specific user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `related_name` and it is necessary to use.

`request.user.user_is_blocking`